# making SKAction perform like animateWithDuration

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction, animatewithduration

I'm currently in the process of converting one of my projects over to **SpriteKit**, and I'm having some trouble with my conversions of `animateWithDuration` to `SKAction MoveByY: duration:`  First is the fact that `animateWithDuration` gives you a nice aesthetic speeding up and slowing down which is lost in `SKAction`. Annoying, but not game breaking. Second is the fact that `animateWithDuration` will calculate its end position immediately, whereas `SKAction` calculates its position constantly. This is a problem for me because I have a gameboard where a row of `spriteNodes` are moving down the screen. If a node in the middle of this row is deleted, I need the nodes below that node to move up to the now vacant position(s). This means that they are going to a moving target, and using `SKAction` they overshoot the position. I could solve this buy adding another `SKAction`, but then I have to account for the pieces falling at different speeds and it starts to get messy fast. I was wondering if anyone had a nice clean solution that didn't involve guesswork? Ideally I would just run the `animateWithDuration` on the `spriteNode`, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

This was my initial animation code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:collapseSpeed animations:^{[[[_activePiecesVerticalOne objectAtIndex:piecesInArrayOne - 1] imageView] setCenter:CGPointMake (30, _positionOfLastObjectArrayOne )]; }];
```

and this is my new code:

```
SKAction *collapseUp = [SKAction moveToY:positionOfLastObjectArrayOne duration:collapseSpeed];
collapseUp.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseInEaseOut;  //thanks Can!
SKAction *correctPosition = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:correctionVariable duration:.1];
SKAction *theAnimation = [SKAction group:@[collapseUp, correctPosition]];

[[_fallingPiecesRowOne objectAtIndex:piecesInArrayOne - 1] runAction:theAnimation];
```

Apologies to Can, as I was actually already using moveTo and not moveBy. The variable correctPosition = fallingPiecesSpeed * 25. fallingPieceSpeed is -.1, which is how far every falling piece is moved every .01 seconds via the update method. I rationalized that during the .25 seconds it takes to animate the piece up, it was missing 25 of these -.1 movement increments and thus implemented this to try and fix my issue. I believe that using the animateWithDuration, these movement increments would be stored and applied to the piece as it falls, which is what I'm missing with SKAction. This solution seems to work ok as long as I keep fallingPieceSpeed at -.1, but cranking it up to -.3 gives me major inconsistencies on where the pieces end up.

Hopefully this makes sense. As I mentioned, I was hoping to bypass all of this with a cleaner approach, but I may have to just keep tinkering with this to find my solution :S

Comment: And the `positionOfLastObjectArrayOne`, how are you getting that?

Comment: Ohh ya, sorry:          positionOfLastObjectArrayOne = [[_fallingPiecesRowOne lastObject] position].y;       As pieces are spawned at the top of the screen they are added to fallingPiecesRowOne. When the first moves out of the way a new one is spawned and added to the array. This works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `animateWithDuration:`, I assume you know the final position, right? Then, instead of using `SKAction +moveByY:duration:` use `SKAction +moveToY:duration:`.

And the "speeding" you want, is a simple timing function, which in the case of an SKAction, can be changed on the instance object `SKAction -setTimingMode:`

So essentially:

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:someYValue duration:0.15];
action.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseInEaseOut;
```

### Edit

It's hard for me to assess the issue, there's a lot of things involved, and my knowledge of SpriteKit is not that big, but I know about Core Animation.

My biggest worry is that you're taking values from SpriteKit which may have not been fully committed to the model layer. Notice this term, there are two forms of a layer, the model layer and the presentation layer, the model layer retains the actual properties of a layer, and the presentation layer is a intermediary layer that has the current animated properties. You can actually access all this properties via the `view.layer.presentationLayer`.

A general rule of thumb to deal with animations, is to do everything via relative values. So rows that need to move up should do it based on a fixed amount (the sprite's height), so the `moveByY:` isn´t as bad as it first seemed, but make sure that everything is relative.

Another alternative, is that you use SKPhysics, where the last row keeps pushing things up, and all the other pieces fall with gravity/bounciness.

Comment: action.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseInEaseOut; = EXACTLY what i was looking for, thank you very much :)  I'll try using moveTo instead, but I'm not sure that will do what I'm trying to accomplish... I'll post another comment asap with my results.

Comment: Try pasting the old `animateWithDuration` code, then, so we can imitate the functionality with the SKAction.

Comment: Ok. You have given me some things to work with and I appreciate your help! I'll let you know if I figure something out different than we have discussed. Happy Coding!

Comment: p.s.  one glaring flaw: me using "skaction group" instead of "skaction sequence". noob mistake there...